# Understanding Intermediate value theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I will first state the theorem in my words and then my problem.

> If function $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a) > 0 > f(b)$ or $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$ then the function has **at least** a zero in $[a,b]$.

---

I have two problems with this theorem.

1. My book does not say that "**at least**" part, it just says "a zero", is not the book wrong ? example : $f(x) = x^3 - 5x^2 +  6x$ on $[-100,100]$.
2. Let $f$ be such that $f(x) = x^2$. Now $f$ is certainly continuous on $[-1,1]$ but $f(-1) = f(1) = 1$. Thus it does not satisfy any of the last two conditions still it has a zero at $x = 0$. What have I missed ?

Comment: "a zero" does not mean "one zero"

Comment: @zhw. I thought it meant like "a car" , "a dog" ? excuse my bad English.

Comment: Consider: Yes we have a dog. In fact we have two of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the statement of the theorem. The first issue is just a grammar convention. Here, the phrase "there is a zero in $[a,b]$" implicitly means "at least one zero."

Second, this statement is *not* biconditional. That is, the statement is of the form

$$\text{hypothesis} \implies \text{ there is a zero}$$

which does NOT mean

$$\text{there is a zero} \implies \text{hypothesis}.$$

If you could use the theorem in the reverse direction, we write

$$\text{hypothesis} \iff \text{ there is a zero}.$$

The forward arrow is an "if then" statement, and the double-headed arrow is an "if and only if" statement.

Comment: Oh I think I realise my mistake now. I did not know the difference between iff and if then. Tell me if I am correct, If p then q means if p is true then q is also true but not in reverse. p iff q means if p is true then q and converse is also true ?

Comment: Yes exactly. $\text{}$

Comment: "iff " is an abbreviation for "if and only if".